# ¿Como hacer responsive mi tabla de bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, bootstrap

espero me puedan apoyar con el problema que tengo, tengo una tabla la cual en cierto px cuando se reduce la pantalla se sale de mi elemento `card` y ya trate con la propiedad `table-responsive`, pero no me dio resultado.

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header">Vacantes</div>
<div class="card-body">
    <a asp-action="Crear" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Crear nuevo</a>
    <p class="card-text">En este apartado vas a poder dar de alta nuevos procesos de vacante.</p>

    <table class="table table-hover table-responsive" id="tablaVacantes">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>FechaInicio</th>
                <th>Plaza</th>
                <th>Entrevistador</th>
                <th>Departamento</th>
                <th>Puesto</th>
                <th>Estatus</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach(var vacante in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@vacante.FechaInicio</td>
                    <td>@vacante.NombrePlaza</td>
                    <td>@vacante.NombreEntrevistador</td>
                    <td>@vacante.NombreDepartamento</td>
                    <td>@vacante.NombrePuesto</td>
                    <td>@vacante.NombreEstatus</td>
                    <td>
                        <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" asp-action="Editar" asp-route-idVacante="@vacante.IdVacante"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" asp-action="Borrar" asp-route-idVacante="@vacante.IdVacante"><i class="bi bi-trash"></i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

Este es mi html y se ve asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe como prodria hacer un `collapse`? y que se vera asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: encima de tu etiqueta table, crea un div con la clase `table-responsive` y que ese div encierre todo el table... ah y también quita el `table-responsive` del table, me avisas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Cris.

Comment: A usted, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tu `table` le podrías dar las siguientes propiedades:

```
.table {
   display: block !important;
   overflow-x: auto !important;
   width: 100% !important;
 }
```

Otra alternativa es que crees una etiqueta `div` encima del table, que ese `div` tenga la propiedad `table-responsive` y que encierre a todo el table, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-hover" id="tablaVacantes">
    //...
  </table>
</div>
```

Puedes checar la [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/tables/#responsive-tables) acerca de esto.